# How to set Height of items in XAML so they always occupy the same proportion of available space in parent ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with the following ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Height="???" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

My question is, how do I set the Height of the TextBlock in the template so that it automatically assumes `ItemsControl.Height div ItemsCount` amount of vertical space?

When there's only one item, I'd like it to be the full height of container, when there're two, each should be half the size, and so on.

If possible, I'd prefer to do this completely in XAML to keep my ViewModel clean of UI logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `UniformGrid` as your `ItemsPanelTemplate` and bind the `Rows` property to the number of items in your `ItemsControl`, like so:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I did not test this code, so you need to check it, but I think the idea is clear.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by John below, this code is even easier:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Actually, it's simpler than that. UniformGrid will take care of the Row count for you automatically if you set Columns="1". And you need to use ItemsControl.ItemsPanel for this instead of ItemTemplate.

Comment: Oh, this is cool. I did not know about that. Thanks for the tip!

And thanks for pointing out the "bug" in my sample code. I accidentally wrote "ItemTemplate" instead of "ItemsPanel". Fixed it in the above message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and remember this as an intellectual exercise as I'm very new to WPF. I have no doubt I'll be corrected in due course. I *think* that you can specify a constant proportion by appending a % sign to the Height value i.e. Height="50%". This is deceptive, as it will add up all the numeric values of the heights of elements inside the parent, and size each one as its proportion of this sum. For example, three textblocks each of height="50%" would each have a height (50/150)*height of datatemplate = 1/3.

Comment: I suppose, you are thinking of a "star-sized" Grid, but that won't work here because the number of rows is not known and not fixed. Well, there might be a working solution, but I think it is a lot more work.